# space between item and paragraph in enumerate

Tags: spacing, enumerate

I'm writing a list in this form:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Question 1...
\item[a)] Something 1...
\item[b)] Something 2...

\item Question 2...
\item[a)] Something 3...
\item[b)] Something 4...

\item Question 3...
\item[a)] Something 5...
\item[b)] Something 6...

... and so on.

\end{enumerate}
```

I'd like to control the spaces between items in a way that the spaces between questions are different from that between question and items `a), b)`. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, of course -- unfortunately you are misusing the `enumerate` environment severely, in my point of view

Comment: I've removed the [tag:biblatex] tag since it has nothing to do with `biblatex`

Answer (score 4):

Use nested `enumerate` levels, the spacing is adapted to the nesting level then.

If the `enumitem` package is used, the labels of the `2nd` level can be adjusted without using `\item[a)]` explicitly.

The separation of items can be set with the `itemsep=...` option (not done here, however)

(Or use the `enumerate` package for label changes only -- see the documentation please).

Side note: Using a proper `answers` etc. package would increase the usability of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


% Change the labels of the second level to use lower case letters of type a)  -- default is (a) etc.  
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*)}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Question 1...
\begin{enumerate}
\item Something 1...
\item Something 2...
\end{enumerate}
\item Question 2...
\begin{enumerate}
\item Something 3...
\item Something 4...
\end{enumerate}
\item Question 3...
\begin{enumerate}
\item Something 5...
\item Something 6...
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]